# Crosstab Query can't find textbox

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot-table, crosstab

Hopefully someone can help me with this Access problem.

I have a continuous form (frmsearch), which is based on a crosstab query (qrytags.)

The query looks like this

```
PARAMETERS [forms]![frmsearch]![txttag] Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM tbltags.Tag
SELECT tbl_Assets.AssetTitle, tbl_Assets.AssetNumber
FROM tbltags RIGHT JOIN tbl_Assets ON tbltags.AssetnumberFK=tbl_Assets.AssetNumber
WHERE (((tbltags.tag)=[forms]![frmsearch]![txttag]))
GROUP BY tbl_Assets.AssetTitle, tbl_Assets.AssetNumber
PIVOT tbltags.Tag;
```

I'm trying to make it so that when a tag (keyword) is typed into a textbox (txttag) on the form, it filters the results in the query, and ultimately the continuous form.

However, the criteria in the query can't seem to find the textbox, and therefore, the query doesnt filter?

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know query can't seem to find the textbox? Are you getting an Enter Parameter dialog?

Comment: When i run/open the query, i get an enter parameter box. But when the form is opened, i don't get an enter parameter box, and entering a value into the textbox doesn't change the results of the query

Comment: You need to first enter textbox value in form then open query. Otherwise refresh the open query.

Comment: @parfait Is there a way to refresh the query using a button on the form? i tried me.requery but that didnt work

Comment: `Me.Requery` runs for the current form not an opened query. Why not open query after entering textbox? Otherwise create a datasheet/continuous form of crosstab and requery that each time.

Comment: @Parfait Opening the query after entering a value in the text box isnt as user friendly as this need to be. Would i be able to create a subform in acviewdatasheet, and then requery that when a button is pressed? Thanks so much for your help by the way! :)

Comment: Yes, place datasheet mentioned above inside a main form (where button sits) and have button requery the datasheet: `Me.SubformName.Form.Requery`. But be careful since crosstab can easily change columns depending on data values and form is designed at current crosstab design. Be sure to use crosstab's `PIVOT IN()` clause to predefine columns.

Comment: @parfait I tried to create a subform based on the crosstab query but i can't make it work. I think this problem is slightly too advanced for me at the moment.... so im gonna leave it for the time being. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: If you know an easier way of searching on tagwords (keyword search) then that would be great, but for now, i'll just search on title of the assets